# How to determine if modules are supported in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, module

When I enable the -Weverything custom compiler flag and modules are supported in Xcode, it tells me to switch to using modules - so I change this type of thing:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

to this:

```
@import Foundation;
```

...and everything is fine until someone later imports one of my classes into their legacy projects that do not have modules enabled, at which point they have to revert the @import to a #import.

My question is this:  Is it possible to wrap these in some sort of preprocessor macro to pick out the correct one at compile time?

Example of what I'm hoping for:

```
#ifdef MODULES_SUPPORTED
    @import Foundation;
#else
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif
```

Thanks

Jase

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an old question, but needed to know how to do this too. Here is a way to do it:

```
#ifdef __has_feature(modules)
    @import Foundation;
#else
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif
```

Reference: [CLANG LANGUAGE EXTENSIONS](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#checks-for-standard-language-features)